# Why is this form invalid all the time

Tags: php, forms, validation, zend-framework, orm

I have this form which is just one field, the method isValid() keeps treating it as if it was invalid everytime I submit it, i've been submitting text like it should be

```
//form
class CategoryForm extends Form
{
 public function __construct()
 {
    parent::__construct('category');

    $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');

    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'name',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'options' => array('label' => 'Name',),
        'required' => true,
            'filters'  => array(
                array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
            ),
    ));

    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'submit',
        'attributes' => array(
            'type'  => 'submit',
            'value' => 'Save',
            'id' => 'submitbutton',
        ),
    ));
 }
}
```

and this would be the faulty part, I supose, and because it is kind of working there are no error messages.

```
//validation clause at controller
 $category = new Category;
 $form = new CategoryForm();
 $form->bind($category);
 $request = $this->getRequest();

    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $form->setInputFilter($category->getInputFilter());
        $form->setData($request->getPost());

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getEntityManager();
            $em->persist($category);
            $em->flush();

            $this->flashMessenger()->addSuccessMessage('category Saved');

            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('category');
        }
    }
```

If I change The code to this it persists the data

```
public function addAction()
{
    $form = new CategoryForm();
    $form->get('submit')->setValue('Add');

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $category = new category();
        $form->setInputFilter($category->getInputFilter());
        $form->setData($request->getPost());
        $form->isValid();

        $category->exchangeArray($form->getData());
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $em->persist($category);
        $em->flush();
        $this->flashMessenger()->addSuccessMessage('Category Saved');
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('category');
    }
     return new ViewModel(array(
        'category' => $category,
        'form' => $form
    ));
}
```

Comment: *there are no error messages* - does your system have error reporting enabled? If not, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: need a zend-framework expert in here

Comment: What does the isValid function check for? What makes a valid form?

Comment: there are no php errors, must have something to do with the validation, not sure what is wrong tho

Comment: like the array states it checks that is has value and that it is a string

Comment: Why is there a comma here: array('label' => 'Name',)

Comment: I know for a fact it is the validation, because if i remove the if, it does persist the data

Comment: it's an array i don't think is matters, but i'll remove it

Comment: Can you show the code where you actually assign the submitted values to the form?

Comment: put a else and use $form->getErrorMessages() to get the errors

Comment: it says the method getErrorMessages, is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you actually passing the submitted values to the form before validating?

I usually do something like this:

```
if ($this->_request->isPost() && $form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())) { 
...
Your save code here...
```

If you are doing that then check the form for what raised a validation error...

```
var_dump($form->getMessages());
```

Comment: var_dump from messages array (size=0)
  empty

Comment: Suppose show the relevant code.  Seeming more likely that its not the issue you think it is.  What validators are even set?  I see none.  Well other than `required`.  Can you step through that code?

Comment: that's the thing it just one, and it still says it isn't valid, also just one field.

Comment: Sorry.  Not as familiar with ZF2 as I am 1.x.

Comment: it's ok It might be that I should add the id field, even if it's empty for the isvalid()

Comment: ^ makes sense...`'name' => 'name'`, is a little generic, does the form succeed in associating the post value with the form element?  Id expect `id` to be required (maybe it aliases `name`?).  Curious if after you call `setData` can you pull value from element... `$form->getElement('name')->getValue();`

Comment: I don't have that function on my form class